# Losing exception type when rethrowing an exception from a catch block

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Today I found a bug in a `catch` block:

```
catch (const exception& e){
    // do something
    // throw e; <-- bug!
    throw;    // <-- right thing to do
}
```

Basically if I rethrow the exception `e` *explicitly*, I get a new `std::exception` reconstructed, in fact the message from the `what()` method was the default `std::string`, instead of my custom built message.

What is the explanation? I thought that `throw;` is only a shorthand of `throw ExceptionJustCaught;`.

Comment: It's the difference between a value and a reference.

Comment: This is a very important concept that is often overlooked (and in my opinion a tricky bit of syntax that should at least be a warning when compiled..). Great question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Exception objects are a bit special. They're constructed in a special place in memory, and their lifetime is determined by the catch block in which they're caught.

If you say `throw e;`, the lifetime of the original exception ends at the end of the catch block, and you are throwing a new exception by copying `e`, thus producing a classical **slicing** problem: Since `e` is a polymorphic reference to an object whose dynamical type is usually more-derived than `std::exception`, you end up slicing off the derived part of the object.

By contrast, `throw;` is a special statement that reactivates the original exception, so that it is no longer caught, and its lifetime does *not* end at the end of the block anymore. In fact, if you catch by non-constant reference, you can keep modifying the exception object and rethrow and thus communicate a state change up the lower catch blocks. But bear in mind that rethrowning is different from throwing a new exception!

Answer (score 9):

Just a `throw` throws the current exception by reference. `throw e` copy constructs a new exception to throw. This is much the same way `return` works.

Comment: "by reference". Exact, this should not lose the right implementation of `what()`, which bears my message.

Comment: Can you post a complete, compilable code example with as few lines as possible that demonstrates the problem? Most likely, your copy constructor doesn't preserve the message.

Comment: Kerrek's answers looks correct, I was suspecting there is a slicing problem, so I won't edit the question as I think it's correctly answered. Maybe David's is right with just different words, but honestly it's not clear enough.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: We're saying the same thing. You'd have precisely the same problem with `return`.